# C# transparent canvas over OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl

I have the following layout in C# where WindowsFormHost host a OpenGL window. I would like to add a transparent canvas over it where I could draw 2D stuff. However this code doesn't work. Please help.

```
 mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <WindowsFormsHost Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ScannerViewPanel"/>
        <Canvas Background="Transparent"/>
```

Edit: after I add the canvas, the OpenGL content is not shown, but only the opaque canvas. I tried to make the canvas transparent, to set Opacity to 0, it's still Opaque.

Comment: What doesn't work?  Does the canvas not show up? Do you get an error?  Compile time or runtime?  We need more information to help you out.

Comment: Any more brilliant ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751797.aspx):

> In a WPF user interface, you can change the z-order of elements to
>   control overlapping behavior. A hosted Windows Forms control is drawn
>   in a separate HWND, so it is always drawn on top of WPF elements.

You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have an ["Airspace"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) problem. This is exacerbated by the fact that you're using OpenGL - an API that has no solution to this problem. If you were using DirectX, you could do [this](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/08/11/airspace-shmairspace/).